# Pre-populating tabs for multiple signers

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to pre-populate a contract using Docusign's `docusign-esign`. I understand that you can create an envelope and pass JSON through. I can also add text tabs for specific signers however, I don't understand how to populate fields that ALL signers can see?

I can only seemingly populate texttabs for each signer. When another signer looks at the document the tabs seem to be empty.

### Update

This suggests to use the `secureField` [DocuSign: I need the first recipient of a document to know the name of signers assigned via templateRoles when creating an envelope from a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706245/docusign-i-need-the-first-recipient-of-a-document-to-know-the-name-of-signers-a?rq=1) option - However, I can't seem to find that in the UI of docusign or in the API.

I am also unsure whether to use 'templateRoles' or 'inlineTemplates'?

Answer (score 1):

**Display Secure Field Initial Value to all recipients** is an account level setting. In the new DocuSign experience it is now called as "**When a document is sent, write the initial value of the fields for all recipients**."

You can use the [updateAccountSettings](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/updateSettings/) API and set the **signerShowSecureFieldInitialValues** property. See the full list of your account settings [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/create/)

> PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/settings

```
{
  "accountSettings": [
    {
      "name": "signerShowSecureFieldInitialValues",
      "value": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

You can also set it using the DocuSign Admin UI. Instructions [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-sending-settings)

If  you are using the older (classic) DocuSign experience the instructions are [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-sending-and-signing-options).

Comment: This does not work for other signers names though? Am I correct? So a Tenant to see a landlord's name or a landlord to see a tenants' name in a rental agreement?

Comment: This will work for all Signers. If you set the value of a Field, all signers can see the value. But only the signer assigned to that field can update the value.

Comment: Using https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client, the code https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/master/src/api/AccountsApi.js#L1986 looks like it needs `accountSettingsInformation` but I get an error

Comment: Can you please post your code to update the account Settings

Comment: @AlexChin Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it addressed your question. Let me know if you have any follow up questions.